# How to create a workout routine based on the goal physique?

Tags: workout-routines, workout, physique

Currently I am following Jason Blaha's Ice Cream Fitness 5x5 Novice Program. Different workouts will result in different body physiques. So how do you create your own workout routine so that it will eventually lead to your goal physique?

Answer (score 3):

There are numerous [body building programs](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/11986/7091) out there that you can move into. In the beginning, I'd recommended sticking with a good compound strength training program. [The one you mentioned](https://www.muscleandstrength.com/workouts/jason-blaha-ice-cream-fitness-5x5-novice-workout) seems to fit that category nicely.

I'd additionally recommend sticking with it until you (at least) hit the [intermediate strength standards](http://www.exrx.net/Testing/WeightLifting/StrengthStandards.htm) on your compound lifts.

The hypertrophy gains of benching 8 reps of 200lbs will be more than 8 reps of 185. If you start too early down the hypertrophy road, you'll struggle (literally) with strength gains as that won't be what you're training for.

Additionally, body building and hypertrophy is (largely, pardon the pun) for physique and aesthetics. As where the strength training you're learning now will be critical for a long and healthy life.