# How is energy derived from muscle, fat and glucose at different intensities?

Tags: weight-loss, muscle, muscle-loss

I have learned that during aerobic exercising the body converts different sources of energy: glucose, fat and muscle. However, different ratios are used in different situations.

So what are the ratios by intensity? I once had a link to a page where this was explained, the Wikipedia article about [exercise intensity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exercise_intensity) lacks muscle tissue as energy source.

Also, the ratio of these sources changes with time of activity. I heard that after about 30-40 min of cardio the main source of energy switches from glucose to fat. How does this affect the amount of muscles burned?

Comment: What!? Calories come from muscle? I don't understand. Do calories come from muscles!?

Comment: basically i meant when body breaks down muscle to use it as energy.

Comment: If your body is to the point of breaking down muscle for energy, you are WAY far over length of exercise, or you have some disease state showing up. Fat stores will be used long before muscle, so unless you are 3% body fat and working out for 5-6 hours, you should have plenty before your body turns to muscle.

Comment: Whether or not you SHOULD be burning muscle is good info, but irrelevant to this question. If you are a lean athlete and need to cut mass to meet a weight requirement down the road, for example, cutting muscle is a valid option.

Comment: i know i'd have plenty but i am looking for a source that listed how much muscle, even when i have plenty, would be burning.

Comment: waiting for answer :D lol

Comment: You might find [this](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/11636/why-does-cardio-aerobic-exercise-lead-to-muscle-loss/11640#11640) answer interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Your muscles and brain run on glycogen. More importantly for this question, Glycogen fuels your muscles. When you exercise with high intensity for 20 minutes or more this is when your body switches from a primarily carbohydrate based metabolism to a fat metabolism, as duration increases so does amount of fat burned for fuel.

**SO IN ADDITION**

> I suppose high-intensity would be > 70% V02 max Carbs are used as primary fuel here, if low-intensity or under < 30% V02 max, fats are primary fuel.
>
> So if the total energy expenditure is relatively high, 50% from carbohydrates, 40% from fat, and 10% from muscle, which creates lactic acid.
>
> If your prolong your exercise, you shift from carbohydrate dominant metabolizing toward fat metabolism. This is due to an increase in breakdown of triglycerides (cholesterol) or (glycerol + free-fatty-acids).
>
> So in reference to the muscle that is used, it actually comes from the glycogen, as the primary source of carbs (keep in mind you're also burning fat after 20min) for the first hour or so.
>
> 85% V02 max and you're burning 60% muscle glycogen, 15% glucose, 20% FFA, <5% muscle triglycerides

Fat burns in the flame of carbohydrates
http://www.depts.ttu.edu/hess/mccomb/documents/ess3305/ppt/chap04.pdf

Comment: I am telling you its ratios. All sources are used but at different ratios. From what i read it was like at beginning 2% from muscle.

Comment: It is ratios. It's not like eating the steak, then the peas, then the potatoes. It all gets burned at different ratios according to intensity.

Comment: Oh I see...I'm sure if it's burning glycogen your % of muscle being "burned" is minimal...I'll look for a resource and update. Thanks.

Comment: updated answer, provided reference, and explanation. Apologies for first answer, maybe i was thinking too newb on the topic.

Comment: -1 again for a rather glaring mistake. Lactate (the actual term for what is commonly called lactic acid) does NOT come from burning muscle. I'm also not sure where you got your quote, as it is not from the link that you provided. If you do look at around slide 33 onward, there is good information on the ratios, what lactate actually is/does (It's a secondary fuel source), and where muscle energy comes from.

Comment: Which quote? "Fat burns in the flame of carbohydrates" is in the article I referenced. And actually, Lactic acid is the by product of carbohydrates used as energy (muscle glycogen), when the carbohydrates break down, during a time when the oxygen level is low. SO @JohnP , if that's not "Burning", and not in the literal sense, I'm not sure what answer you would like. "When the oxygen level is low, carbohydrate breaks down for energy and makes lactic acid." - WebMD. Now I answered the question, and gave a resource, your mind-numbing response is trivial in lieu of the question asked.

Comment: "But when oxygen is limited, the body temporarily converts pyruvate into a substance called lactate, which allows glucose breakdown--and thus energy production" - ScientificAmerican I never said burning muscles create lactic acid, I said IF THE TOTAL ENERGY EXPENDITURE IS HIGH...blah...10% from muscle, (pay attention) WHICH CREATES LACTIC ACID.

Comment: "Contrary to popular opinion, lactate or, as it is often called, lactic acid buildup is not responsible for the muscle soreness felt in the days following strenuous exercise. Rather, the production of lactate and other metabolites during extreme exertion results in the burning sensation often felt in active muscles..." - http://www.scientificamerican.com/article.cfm?id=why-does-lactic-acid-buil

Comment: From your post: "So if the total energy expenditure is relatively high, 50% from carbohydrates, 40% from fat, and 10% from muscle, which creates lactic acid." And, lactate != lactic acid, despite the common misconception.

Comment: someone is confused here @JohnP. From your comment: "Lactate (the actual term for what is commonly called lactic acid)" followed by, "lactate != lactic acid" ...

Comment: However, I do see your point about Lactic Acid being a fuel - http://www.nytimes.com/2006/05/16/health/nutrition/16run.html?_r=0 I would +1 but you negged me a couple times..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11164/discussion-between-johnp-and-hituptony)

Answer (score 0):

The ratios do not change based on duration, the ratios change based on the intensity of the exercise. At low intensities, you can get nearly all of your energy from fat, but the amount of power that can be generated by fat is limited, so as you increase your intensity, you will need to start burning more carbohydrate, and therefore the ratio of carbohydrate to fat will increase.

It might help to think of fat metabolism as a furnace that is very efficient but can't put out much heat; if you need to get the house warmer you might need to turn on the electric heater (carb metabolism) to produce extra heat.

This is somewhat related to duration because long-duration events are generally at a lower intensity than short-duration events, and therefore will depend more on fat as an energy source.